Layout Issue on IOS Device
I got an issue on IOS Device when develop a responsive web-app.
Sometimes, when I scroll down to my input, the layout at the back is overlaid on my input as shown
Layout issue
I tried hiding the entire layout at the bottom but then a black background would replace it.
I try to debug but can not find what this issue is.
Please help me solve this issue. Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
